# Unable to confirm timezone while setting crontab for different unix users

Tags: linux, unix, users, timezone

On our production server, UCT timezone has been set for server i.e. for root user  but for local technical user different timezone is set in .base_profile.
I want to set cron as per CET but server timezone is UCT and I am unable to confirm what exactly timezone I have to refer? I cannot set cron from root due to insufficient privileges  , condition is cron must be set from local account.
My question is which timezone I have to refer either my root's timezone or local account timezone ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to refer to the system time unless you want to change your profile timezone look at this link https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-set-time-zone-per-user-basis/  maybe it will help

Comment: I have already mentioned that there is 2 timezones present, profile timezone is already changed and its different from roots timezone.